# How to fix "this is undefined" in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, methods

I've created a new component in VueJS and defined two methods.
One method is action(vuex) and another one is regular method.

actionTypes.js

```
const TOGGLE_PREVIEW = 'togglePreview';
```

component

```
method: {
  ...mapActions([actionTypes.TOGGLE_PREVIEW]),
  onClickPreview: () => {
    this.togglePreview();
  }
```

It occurred an error; `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'togglePreview' of undefined`.

Comment: If `actionTypes` is undefined, you need to create the object with the const in it. Where are you defining `actionTypes` in the component?

Comment: I've imported actionTypes.js.

Comment: can you include the import code in your question?

Comment: I think this is enough for the issue.

Comment: You're using an arrow function. You'll have to use a normal function instead if you want to use `this`. Like so `onClickPreview()  { this.togglePreview(); }`

Comment: Could you please give me the reason?
Please submit your comment as an answer.

Comment: @FrozenICE [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) do not have their own bindings for `this`, which is why it it is undefined here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a Vue instance is created Vue proxies data, methods, props and injections on the instance for easy access. To proxy methods it uses [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) ..

> The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   `this` keyword set to the provided value

However this doesn't work on arrow functions since their scope cannot be bound and they inherit their parent's scope. So the solution in your case is to use a normal function instead so that it's `this` scope can be correctly bound to the Vue instance.

```
methods: {
  ...mapActions([actionTypes.TOGGLE_PREVIEW]),
  onClickPreview() {
    this.togglePreview();
  }
}
```